# ¿Cómo actualizar un documento en Mongodb con Mongoose si hay campos required que no actualizo?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Tengo `Schemas` mongoose de documentos que definen campos como requeridos (`required = true`), al hacer una actualización con el método `findOneAndUpdate()` del modelo me tira una excepción de que debo colocar los campos requeridos, pero yo solo quiero actualizar un campo y los demás no... ¿Como puedo solucionar esto?

Ejemplo de Schema con campo requerido:

```
title: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Title required']
  }
```

Mensaje de error: validation failed y los campos que son requeridos.